# How can I install a certificate into the local machine store programmatically using c#?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, certificate, makecert

I have a certificate generated via MakeCert.  I want to use this certificate for WCF message security using PeerTrust.  How can I programmatically install the certificate into the "trusted people" local machine certificate store using c# or .NET?

I have a CER file, but can also create a PFX.

Comment: Btw - i know the details of Makecert and trust.  Please, just looking for suggestions on installing the certificate using programmatic c# or installshield.  thanks!

Comment: any idea how to do this in c program?? any API in windows??

Answer (score 67, accepted):

I believe that this is correct:

```
using (X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.TrustedPeople, StoreLocation.LocalMachine)) 
{
   store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
   store.Add(cert); //where cert is an X509Certificate object
}
```

Comment: This installs certificate successfully, But when I opens Manage Private Keys option for private key in personal store, it gives "no keys found for certificate" error.

Comment: I guess this answer;s now void as X509Store is not disposable.

Comment: @mit did you find a solution for "no private key found for this certificate"?

Comment: @mit Were you looking at the "CurrentUser" store? then you need to change the `StoreLocation` to `StoreLocation.LocalMachine`.

Answer (score 48):

The following works good for me:

```
private static void InstallCertificate(string cerFileName)
{
    X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(cerFileName);
    X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.TrustedPublisher, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);

    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
    store.Add(certificate);
    store.Close();
}
```

Comment: For storing certificate in `Personnel` node, choose the enum value as `StorName.My`. For storing certificate in `Trusted Root Certification Authorities` node, choose the enum value as `StorName.Root`.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of installing the certificate to LocalMachine which requires elevated privileges you can add it to "CurrentUser" (works for me).

```
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.TrustedPeople, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
store.Add(cert); //where cert is an X509Certificate object
store.Close();
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  This was preferable for me as this will be running in a self hosted service that is executed (multiple instances) at runtime.  No way to provide UAC prompt.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

I had to use X509KeyStorageFlags.**PersistKeySet** | X509KeyStorageFlags.**MachineKeySet** flags to resolve *"Keyset does not exist"* error that occurred later on attempt to use the certificate:

```
X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(pfxPath, password, X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
using (X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine))
{
     store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
     store.Add(certificate);
     store.Close();
}
```

Thanks to this article: [Private key of certificate in certificate-store not readable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13231858/private-key-of-certificate-in-certificate-store-not-readable)