# Add an X509 certificate to a store in code

Tags: c#, certificate, x509certificate

This code will add a x509 cer cert file into the certificate store (using `System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates`):

```
    var filename = "Cert.cer";
    var cert = new X509Certificate2(filename);
    var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);

    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
    store.Add(cert);
```

Where the certificate has been generated with:

```
makecert -r -pe -sky exchange -n "CN=Blah" Cert.cer -sv Cert.pvk
```

But - this will add the certificate into the "Personal" certificates of the currentuser - how can I add the certificate to a different collection of certificates - in my case I want to add to the "Trusted People" certificates for currentuser.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I install a certificate into the local machine store programmatically using c#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/566570/how-can-i-install-a-certificate-into-the-local-machine-store-programmatically-us)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var store = new X509Store(StoreName.TrustedPeople, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
```

The First Parameter contains the enumeration for which store to use see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.storename.aspx)

The Second Parameter contains the enumeration for which location to use (eg Computer, Current user) see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.storelocation.aspx)