# How do I deploy a certificate to the Trusted People store in Azure?

Tags: wcf, azure, certificate, x509certificate, nettcpbinding

How can I get a public key certificate deployed to my Worker Role's `Trusted People` store?

I'm using `PeerTrust` for WCF (self-hosted TCP services in Azure):

```
var creds = new ServiceCredentials();
creds.ClientCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.PeerTrust;
```

I know how to reference the certificate both in my `.csdef` and in code. However, I don't know how to take a `.cer` file (with no private key) and actually get it into Azure so it can use it for PeerTrust. The Certificates manager in the online Portal only allow you to upload `.pfx` files (i.e. certificates with the private keys).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm just thinking if you can install the CER from your code when your role was started by using `System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store` and `System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificates2`. You can include your CER into your project with "Copy to Output Directory = Copy always".

Comment: This won't work exactly like that as we deploy this project to 8 different places, and all 8 need different certificates. However, I might be able to pull them from blob storage. Is the installation code obvious? (Not looked for it yet, am on my phone responding right now)

Comment: I think you can retrieve the certificate file from blob and construct the x509certificate instance from the binaries.

Comment: Constructing the instance is easy. How do I actually "deploy" it into the "Trusted People" store, though?

Comment: I'm having a training these days and hopefully will have a try and get back to you soon.

Comment: I just stumbled upon [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6860352/add-an-x509-certificate-to-a-store-in-code). I'm going to try this later today - hopefully this will solve the last missing piece.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this wasn't always the case, but it's currently possible to do this without any custom work at all. Simply edit your service's `.csdef` (cloud service definition) file to include the following - or, if using Visual Studio, use the worker role's properties panel:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceDefinition name="MyService" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition" schemaVersion="2013-10.2.2">
  <WorkerRole name="MyService.Backend" ... >
    <Certificates>
      <Certificate name="backend.example.com.selfsigned" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" />
      <Certificate name="frontend.example.com.selfsigned" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="TrustedPeople" />
    </Certificates>
    <Endpoints>
      <InternalEndpoint name="Internal" protocol="tcp" port="..." />
    </Endpoints>
    ...
  </WorkerRole>
  <WebRole name="MyService.Frontend" ... >
    <Sites>
      <Site name="Web">
        <Bindings>
          <Binding name="WebsitePublicEndpoint" endpointName="Insecure" />
          <Binding name="WebsitePublicEndpoint" endpointName="Secure" />
        </Bindings>
      </Site>
    </Sites>
    <Endpoints>
      <InputEndpoint name="Insecure" protocol="http" port="80" />
      <InputEndpoint name="Secure" protocol="https" port="443" certificate="example.com" />
    </Endpoints>
    <Certificates>
      <Certificate name="backend.example.com" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="TrustedPeople" />
      <Certificate name="frontend.example.com" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" />
      <Certificate name="example.com" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" />
    </Certificates>
    ...
  </WebRole>
</ServiceDefinition>
```

See also [this forum thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/2e5695d4-8a2f-4dd9-a874-9ccdb6a503e7/ms-tech-talk-adding-a-x509-certificate-on-trusted-people-store-in-windows-azure?forum=windowsazuremanagement) and the [worker role service definition file schema documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg557552.aspx).

Also, the Azure portal now supports uploading `.cer` (public-key-only) certificate files. You may have to change the Open File dialog's selection filter - by default it's set to look for `.pfx` files only.

Comment: I think the `.csdef` trick would have worked if I could have somehow gotten the `.cer` file deployed but that part was what didn't work. If the portal now allows you to upload `.cer` files, then this is great news!!

Comment: Yep, it works now - I have a service with a similar configuration running right now. :)