# API to create my own certmgr.exe

Tags: c, windows, winapi, certificate, ssl-certificate

Is there any windows api available to create my own `cermgr.exe`, which installs the `.cer` file to certificate store. If not programatically how to achieve this?

How to install a certificate without using `certmgr.exe` or `certutil.exe`..

I'd like to add some more points here. The certificate file is created and signed by my own. Now I have a `.cer` file. I want to install it in "localMachine root","localMachine trusted publisher". How to do it programatically ( USING WINAPI ).

**Update:**

[This link provides a solution in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566570/how-can-i-install-a-certificate-into-the-local-machine-store-programmatically-us?answertab=active#tab-top), any idea in C to achieve the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should look at "[Certificate and Certificate Store Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380252%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#certificate_and_certificate_store_functions)" in MSDN.

The function to add a certificate in a store is [CertAddEncodedCertificateToStore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376015%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).