# C code equivalent of C# to install certificate

Tags: c#, c, windows, winapi, certificate

I found the below code to install a certificate into local machines trusted publisher. But the code is in C# I want the same to be done in C. How to convert this to C?

```
private static void InstallCertificate(string cerFileName)
{
  X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(cerFileName);
  X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.TrustedPublisher,StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
  store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
  store.Add(certificate);
  store.Close();
 }
```

Any Windows APIS available?

Comment: I found the code in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/566570/how-can-i-install-a-certificate-into-the-local-machine-store-programmatically-us?answertab=active#tab-top  , I intend to do the same but with C programming.

Answer (score 4):

Try to look at libpkix [lib](http://libpkix.sourceforge.net/)

> The purpose of the libpkix library is to provide a widely useful C
>   library for building and validating chains of X.509 certificates,
>   compliant with the latest IETF PKIX standards (namely, RFC 3280). This
>   project aims to provide complete support for all the mandatory
>   features of RFC 3280, as well as a number of optional features.

Comment: I need to use it in my code and it looks like its developed by sunmicrosyste... Is it an opensource??

Answer (score 2):

try this example:

```
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
static int store_cert(SSL_CTX * ctx, X509 * cert)
{
    X509_STORE * x509_store;

    x509_store=SSL_CTX_get_cert_store(ctx);

    if (X509_STORE_add_cert(x509_store, cert)==0)
    {
        printf("ERROR: add certificate\n");
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;

}
```

Comment: SSL_CTX_get_cert_store?? where this function is defined??

Comment: SSL_CTX_get_cert_store is in libssl library, X509_STORE_add_cert is in libcrypto library