# How to programmatically add certificates to BizTalk Groups and Hosts

Tags: c#, .net, biztalk

Does anybody know how I can programmatically add certificates to BizTalk Groups and Hosts with C# .NET? Or does anybody at least know where they are stored, so I can programmatically put them there?

Comment: you want at runtime to decide to which  ssl  "port" to go ??

Comment: My goal is to extend the Cert Wizard from Microsoft so that it also makes this step for me. It should just imort a certificate and put it everywhere it belongs to. Sorry if my explanation wasn't 100% clear, I hope now it's more clear. In the BizTalk Admin Console you can choose certificates e.g. for Hosts, and that's what the tool should do for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to : [How to programmatically install a certificate using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12337721/how-to-programmatically-install-a-certificate-using-c-sharp)

I've used this kind of code and it did the job.
Not sure if you can use this code in your orchestration.. maybe you'll need to call a C# class library helper from your process.

If you want further explanation on where the key is stored: https://seroter.wordpress.com/2007/03/05/building-a-complete-certificate-scenario-with-biztalk-server-2006/