# Recommendation for distributing an application which contains a UWP app and a WCF service

Tags: wcf, uwp, windows-installer, software-distribution, msix

Our application does the following operations. When a user registers on a portal, the application does the following

1. Installs certificates to Local Machine store. Installation of the certificates is done by a Windows Communication Service (WCF)
2. Creates a VPN profile (using Windows.Networking.Vpn APIs)

We need to ship this app to end user which consists of an UWP App, and a Windows Communication Service. We would like the user to install this app with as few clicks as possible and the result should be that user should have UWP app installed as well as the WCF Service installed and running on his/her system. We are looking for guidance relating to the best option to distribute this app to end-users? We are open to distributing this app through Windows store or by sideloading.

Please provide your guidance after taking into consideration all the below scenarios

1. Update/Upgrade of UWP-Application or WCF-Service.
2. Uninstall scenario.
3. How can we distribute this application for Windows 7. (Note: We use XAML Islands to make UWP App running inside WPF)

Thank you

Sujay

Comment: I would like to know more details about the consistence of your application. What do you mean that “Installation of the certificate is done by WCF”, Does this achieved on the client-side? In my opinion, we could programmatically install a certificate using C#.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12337721/how-to-programmatically-install-a-certificate-using-c-sharp/12339231

Comment: Yes, we were trying to install a cert on the client-side in the client-device store. Your reply was helpful. We are all set. Thank you.

Sujay M