# how to install a certificate on trusted root certification authorities using visual studio installer setup project

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

I created an add-in for a company but I need to put it into production, but the problem is that when I created the installer I couldn't place the certificate but the problem is that every time I have to install the add-in I have to install it manually in each computer. Is it possible to place the certificate with the installer? the installer I'm using is from the image below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMSUI.png)

Comment: 1) Try not to use the installer project, https://blog.lextudio.com/the-horrible-facts-on-visual-studio-setup-projects-45e66fe86d8d 2) You can easily automate the steps in PowerShell and then execute that from within an installer.

Comment: I'm sorry. I expressed myself badly, I am doing this because the customer wants to test the add-in before putting it into production, so I need to install it, but it can be different people to test it.

Comment: You can try to create your own custom action in order to achieve this. You can take a look on the  (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12337721/how-to-programmatically-install-a-certificate-using-c-sharp) and (https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-c-sharp-ca.html) threads which could be useful for you.